# Make Back Button Skip 2 (TWO) Pages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, e-commerce

I'm trying to make a back button that changes between `history.go()` and `history.go(-2)` depending on if a specific `div#id` (not a parent to the buttons) is on the page. The `div#id` is generated using `PHP`, the button is `html/js`.

I've spent a few hours trying to figure out how to do this.

**The usage is:**
An eCommerce site: You go from a **category page** (ie. cooking supplies) **to a specific product page** (ie. Pan #1). After adding the product to cart, the page refreshes (no ajax). A div appears stating `"added to cart"`. If you click `history.go(-1)` back, the back button must be clicked x2 to return to the category page.

**Therefore when the "added to cart" div appears, I'd like to change the history.go() to history.go(-2) so the button only needs to be clicked x1 to return the category page.**

Any suggestions? Thanks.

```
<html>
    <a class = “cat1” href="#" onclick="history.go(-1)">Go Back</a>
    <a class = “cat2” href="javascript:history.back(-2)”>Go Back2</a>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($(“.added-message").length > 0) {
        $(“.cat2”).show();
        ////also tried this  $divStyle='style="display:none;"';
    }
});
</script>
```

Also tried stuff like this (sorry it's all jumbled now...)

```
<script>
function CheckExists() {
    var cat1 = document.getElementById(‘cat1’);
    var cat2 = document.getElementById(‘cat2’);

    if (document.querySelector(‘.added-message’) !== null) {
        if (cat2.style.display !== "none") {
            cat2.style.display = “none”;
        } else {
            cat2.style.display = “none”;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: please give your code

Comment: I tried a lot of different stuff and deleted it. Here is a mess of some of what I've tried:
`
<html>
<a class = “cat1” href="#" onclick="history.go(-1)">Go Back</a>
<a class = “cat2” href="javascript:history.back(-2)”>Go Back2</a>
</html>
`
`
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($(“.added-message").length > 0)
    {
        $(“.cat2”).show();
    }
});
</script>
`

Comment: did you try onclick="history.go(-2)"

Comment: <button onclick="goBack()">Go Back 2 Pages</button>

<script>
function goBack() {
    window.history.go(-2);
}
</script>

Comment: Thank you @Akashkumar I added some of the code above but already deleted most because became confused...

Comment: @DilDilshan I tried, but the problem is the (-1) should change to (-2) when a specific div is on page (I think by linking an onclick function or by editing the display:none, display:block etc of 2 separate buttons if div exists).

Comment: try  <a href="javascript: history.go(-2)" id="backLink">Link back</a>

Comment: can i see the div#id code of php. u can pass parameter in url and capture same in php page.php?back=1 or page.php?back=2.

Comment: Hi @Dil, sorry don't clearly understand your question although rly appreciate your help..!! (new to PHP) The back buttons are HTML added to a PHP file, I have to search to find the PHP generating the .added-message div. I thought this would be an easier fix..

Comment: Hi @monace19 Thanks but I need to change from javascript: history.go(-1) to javascript: history.go(-2) only if div .added-message exists.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function myfunc(elem){
    var $elem = $(elem);
    var $window = $(window);

    var docViewTop = $window.scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $window.height();

    var elemTop = $elem.offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}   
    if(myfunc("div.added-message")==true){          
        $(".cat2").attr("href", "javascript:history.go(-2)")
    }
});
```

hope this helps